# How to change info on UAC prompt?

Tags: uac, windows-vista, prompt

On Windows Vista, with UAC enabled, everytime a program that requires administrative priviledges starts, a UAC prompt is displayed. In the box, there are two fields - name and author. How can those be customized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign the application.

http://www.google.com/search?q=authenticode